# Play a Shoutcast Stream on iPhone with HTML5

Tags: iphone, html, audio, shoutcast, icecast

I know this question is already asked in past, but i finally found no answer....

So I got a shoutcast stream, encoding audio/mpeg and I want create a web-app for my iphone to listen to my stream mobile.

I tried several methods of http://mydomain.com:8000/. With semicolon, with stream.nsv, with stream.nsv&type=mp3 and so on...

I tested it everytime with the Safari browser und nothing happened. I tried several options in the html5 audio tag. preload, auto-buffering  etc..... it's still quiet...

Do you have any solutions or snippets or what else?

Thank you :)

Comment: i think you have to debug the code coz there may be other things that might be causing the problems.  Posting snippets may not always help but try to debug your code first

Comment: what version of Shoutcast as they have changed if you use v2 then there is a new way to do it, and it only works for mp3

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 streaming web pp for iPhone.

```
<audio controls="> 
 <source src="http://www.yourstreaming.com" type="audio/ogg" />
 <source src="http://www.yourstreaming.com" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Comment: <audio controls="> 
 <source src="http://www.yourstreaming.com" type="audio/ogg" />
 <source src="http://www.yourstreaming.com" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

Comment: So I tried it with Google Android and it dont works. Is there a method for android? A fallback or something?

Comment: The controls is declared weird, no? on Xhtml, had to be controls='controls' or in html5, just controls without equal something

Answer (score 1):

Try [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) I'm pretty sure it can play shoutcast stream, and it works in iPhone. The player uses HTML5, and supports flash fallback.

Answer (score 0):

you very welcome,sorry i don't know the source for Android,here are links that might help you,good luck with it.
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Mediaelement](http://mediaelementjs.com/) . Its works well on most of mobile devices including iPhone.